# Consulta para relación de tablas en MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

Tengo un problema al no poder idear una consulta que me muestre el ultimo libro que ha donado cada alumnno. Esta es la tabla que estoy utilizando:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Como se puede observar en TBL_LIBROS_DONACION existen registros de alumnos que volvieron a regalar libros. Como consigo el siguiente resultado?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Solo necesito traer el **último libro** que dio **cada alumno**. Este es el código que tengo hasta el momento:

```
SELECT dl.ID_LIBRO, a.ID_ALUMNO
FROM tbl_alumnos as a
INNER JOIN tbl_libros_donacion as dl
    ON dl.FK_ALUMNO = a.ID_ALUMNO
ORDER BY dl.ID_LIBRO DESC LIMIT 1
```

Comment: Que es lo que has intentado?

Comment: Un resultado como la ultima tabla, como menciono, sobre los últimos libros que donaron cada uno de los alumnos

Comment: Hola, tengo la respuesta a tu problema, pero antes debes colocar el código que tienes hasta ahora (por protocolo) para que podamos darte la solución.

Comment: Ya lo edite :) gracias- @the-breaker

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Gracias por todas sus respuestas, las ideas eran más o menos correctas y con base a eso pude resolver el problema. El código quedo de esta manera:

```
SELECT l.FK_ALUMNO, l.ID_LIBRO, l.FECHA_DONACION
FROM tbl_libros_donacion AS l
INNER JOIN(SELECT d.FK_ALUMNO, d.ID_LIBRO, MAX(d.FECHA_DONACION) AS FECHA
       FROM tbl_libros_donacion AS d
       GROUP BY d.FK_ALUMNO) AS ULTIMOS
   ON ULTIMOS.FK_ALUMNO = l.FK_ALUMNO
   AND ULTIMOS.FECHA = l.FECHA_DONACION
```

Answer (score 3):

Puedes hacerlo del modo siguiente

```
SELECT ID_ALUMNO AS DONADOR, ID_LIBRO AS DONACION
FROM TBL_ALUMNOS a
JOIN TBL_LIBROS_DONACION l
ON a.ID_ALUMNO = l.FK_ALUMNO
GROUP BY TBL_ALUMNOS.NOMBRES;
```

> Al final agregas un `GROUP BY` y le indicas que agrupe por la columna
>   de nombres para que de este modo aquellos alumnos que hicieron mas de
>   una donación no aparezcan mas de una vez en tu lista final de alumnos
>   donadores

1. Usamos el `INNER JOIN` para que nos devuelva un conjunto de resultados de las coincidencias entre ambas tablas.
2. Seleccione la pk de `ID_ALUMNO` y la FK de `ID_LIBRO` nadamas que en vez de mandarlos así les coloco un alias para su mejor interpretación

---

**PUEDES MEJORAR LA LECTURA DE TU TABLA AGREGANDO LA COLUMNA DE NOMBRES PARA IDENTIFICAR QUE NO EXISTEN DUPLICIDADES, DEL MODO SIGUIENTE**

```
 SELECT NOMBRES, ID_ALUMNO AS DONADOR, ID_LIBRO AS DONACION
    FROM TBL_ALUMNOS a
    JOIN TBL_LIBROS_DONACION l
    ON a.ID_ALUMNO = l.FK_ALUMNO
    GROUP BY TBL_ALUMNOS.NOMBRES;
```

**Acerca de GROUP BY**

Es una función que nos permite crear un sumario o concentrado de datos que tienen una repetitividad dentro de nuestra consulta; para mayores consultas te dejo un enlace de la documentación oficial de MySQL

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-modifiers.html

**actualización**

> Para poder ordenar los resultados de manera descendiente, es decir que
>   te muestre los registros de todos los donantes, pero desde la fecha
>   mas reciente a la fecha mas antigua; haz uso de order by fecha DESC;
>   la cual te mostrara los registros ordenados por esa consulta, desde el
>   mas reciente hasta el mas antiguo

```
SELECT NOMBRES, ID_ALUMNO AS DONADOR, ID_LIBRO AS DONACION
        FROM TBL_ALUMNOS a
        JOIN TBL_LIBROS_DONACION l
        ON a.ID_ALUMNO = l.FK_ALUMNO
        GROUP BY TBL_ALUMNOS.NOMBRES
        ORDER BY TBL_LIBROS_DONACION.FECHA_DONACION DESC;
```

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta y toda la información. Solo que no entiendo todavía muy bien si el Group By aparte de quitar duplicados, toma el ultimo registro disponible(el más reciente). Por ejemplo ejecute tu consulta y en un resultado salio Luis-a10-d10 y esa no es su donación más reciente, sería más bien d14.

Comment: @Ivan92 te agregué una actualización a mi respuesta espero te sirva

Answer (score 3):

*...lo bueno es que las fechas si están de forma consecutiva...*

En realidad el hecho de que las fechas están consecutivas al visualizar la tabla no es ventaja alguna. Esto por que vas a consultar la tabla y al consultarla tu indicas el orden que necesitas.

Para consultar primero usaremos una función analitica para indicar cual es el más reciente.

```
-- primero proyectamos en este query el ID_LIBRO, la FK_ALUMNO y FECHA_DONACION
    SELECT ID_LIBRO
         , FK_ALUMNO
         , FECHA_DONACION
         -- ROW_NUMBER() es una funcion analitica que se calcula al finalizar el select.
         -- Las funciones analiticas pueden dividir el resultado de una consulta 
         -- en en grupos de filas, al poner PARTITION BY le indicamos que divida en 
         -- grupos donde cada grupo tenga los mismos valores de FK_ALUMNO.
         --
         -- Sobre cada grupo ordenamos la fecha de donación poniendo primero
         -- la más reciente.
         -- ROW_NUMBER() lo que hace es que al primer registro de este grupo
         -- le asigna el valor 1, al segundo el valor 2 y así para cada elemento del
         -- grupo. Este valor asignado se queda en la columna MASRECIENTE
         --
         , ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY FK_ALUMNO
                               ORDER BY FECHA_DONACION DESC) MASRECIENTE
      FROM TBL_LIBROS_DONACION
```

Si te fijas en el query anterior la columna MAS_RECIENTE tiene el valor
de 1 para cada una de las filas que necesitas luego entonces basta ahora con generar una consulta que utilice a la consulta anterior como subconsulta:

```
SELECT T.ID_LIBRO
     , T.FK_ALUMNO
      FROM(
        SELECT ID_LIBRO
             , FK_ALUMNO
             , FECHA_DONACION        
             , ROW_NUMBER() OVER ( PARTITION BY FK_ALUMNO
                                   ORDER BY FECHA_DONACION DESC) MASRECIENTE
          FROM TBL_LIBROS_DONACION
          ) T
      WHERE  T.MASRECIENTE = 1;
```

Quedo atento para cualquier duda o comentario.

Comment: Hola que tal muchas gracias pero me manda un error de sintaxis en la linea donde empieza el ROW_NUMBER

Comment: Aunque ya lo resolviste me gustaría que me compartieras la versión de MySQL que manejas. Yo por mi parte originalmente hice el query sobre Oracle 11g pues no tenía a mano un MySQL. En casa he probado con MariaDB y encontré que me pedía un alias. He editado mi respuesta agregando el alias. Pero lo que me comentas del error de sintaxis en el row_number() se me hace raro. Por eso te pido el número de versión de tu MySQL. Saludos

Comment: row_number es una window function si le marca error es por que debe estar manejando una versión inferior a la 8

Comment: @AlvaroC. La versión de MySQL es 10.1.32. Me fije otra vez en el error y es más bien la palabra OVER que parece no la reconoce y con respecto a la versión de Windows tengo la 8.1.

Answer (score 2):

Basta con solo utilizar un [`GROUP BY`](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp), al establecer una columna que tiene mas de 1 resultado, te mostrara siempre el primero, es decir: si los agrupas por `ID_ALUMNO` cuando vaya a mostrar el `ID_LIBRO` al haber mas de 1 te mostrara el primero

```
SELECT  ID_ALUMNO,ID_LIBRO
FROM tbl_alumnos 
GROUP BY ID_ALUMNO
```

Para que te muestre el ultimo :

> Si necesitas hacer otro orden de seleccion para que sean otros lo alumnos que esten primeros para ser seleccionados en `FROM tb_alumnos` puedes hacer una sub consulta `FROM ("consulta con el resultado esperado") as sub`

```
SELECT  ID_ALUMNO,ID_LIBRO
FROM (SELECT ID_ALUMNO,ID_LIBRO 
           FROM tbl_alumnos 
           ORDER BY FECHA_DONACION DESC) as orden
GROUP BY ID_ALUMNO
```

---

La sub consulta hace falta ya que utilizar el `ORDER BY` en el primer select te ordenara ya el resultado agrupado.